what is the best way to test that a table is not empty in dataform bigquery assertion?
I have a dataform assertion and I want to test that a step returns any data before allowing the next more expensive step to initiate.
What is the most efficient way to write the assertion that must return no rows when there is no data in the table being tested?
The dataset/table involved is massive and any efficiency is appreciated.
Surprised I couldn't find a default setting for "no data" like the "noNulls" approach allowed in the dataform/bigquery documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/assertions

I'd use meta tables, i.e. information_schema - the table storage view contains the amount of rows for each table ...
SELECT 
   TOTAL_ROWS
FROM `myProject`.`region-REGION`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
WHERE
   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dataset id'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'table name'
;


REGION: like EU or US

I have two methods that I am considering.
1st Method
Count rows, generate status column in CTE and check when it is not null:
WITH status_cte AS ( select case when COUNT(*) = 0 then 'table is empty'
end as status FROM 'my_table')
 
SELECT * FROM status_cte 
WHERE status IS NOT NULL

2nd Method
Check the table partition information and any partitions containing no nulls.
In this example the data is partitioned by dates and the dataform has start_date and end_date elements in it.
WITH dates AS (
SELECT date 
FROM UNNEST(generate_date_array(${pipeline_config.START_DATE}, ${pipeline_config.END_DATE}, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) date
), 

ps AS ( 
SELECT 
total_rows, 
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', partition_id)  date 
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name = 'my-table' 
AND SAFE_CAST(partition_id as int) 
BETWEEN cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', ${pipeline_config.START_DATE}) as int64) 
AND cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', ${pipeline_config.END_DATE}) as int64)
ORDER BY partition_id
)

SELECT * FROM dates a
LEFT JOIN ps b
USING(date) 
WHERE total_rows == 0 
OR total_rows IS NULL

This seems like it is cheaper but potentially unnecessarily complex.
